# Octal to text in Java

Tags: java, string, decimal, octal

I have a integer:

```
int octalValue = 103
```

I want to convert this to text in Java. How can I do this?
The expected output would be 'C'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Octal literals need to be prefixed with a `0`:

```
int octalValue = 0103; //89
```

You can then convert it to the corresponding ASCII code:

```
char c = (char) octalValue; //C
```

Comment: This is hardly possible because before I am saving the octal digits in an array and then convert them to a whole integer.

Answer (score 1):

This did it for me:

```
int octalValue = 123;
String abc = Integer.toString(octalValue);
char abcChar = (char) Integer.parseInt(abc, 8);
```

Better solutions might be out there.